# Convert binary to hexadecimal

Tags: python, binary, hex

I'm trying to create a function that takes a binary string and converts it to hex.  So far I've only been able to create a function that can convert an int to hexadecimal.

Here is what I have:

```
def intToHex(num):
    num = abs(num)
    symdict={10:"A",11:"B",12:"C",13:"D",14:"E",15:"F"}
    rlist=[]
    while(num!=0):
        rlist.append(num%16)
        num//=16
    rlist=rlist[::-1]
    for idx, val in enumerate(rlist):
        rlist[idx] = symdict.get(val, str(val))

    print(''.join(rlist))

intToHex(4512)
```

sample output: `11A0`

How can you make a function, without using builtins that converts binary to hexadecimal.  Is it possible to modify my function above for that purpose?

Comment: essentially what you are asking is how you convert a number with base n into a number base m. in your answer you went from a base 10 to base 16. you need to change that to base 2 to base 16. essentially, you have half the logic completed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have int to hex, here are some binary string routines:

**Code:**

```
def bin_to_int(bin):
    return sum([(1 << i) for i, c in enumerate(reversed(bin)) if c == '1'])

def int_to_bin(num):
    bin = ''
    while num:
        bin = '01'[num & 1] + bin
        num = num >> 1
    return bin
```

**Test code:**

```
print(bin_to_int('1001'))
print(int_to_bin(bin_to_int('1001')))
```

**Produces:**

```
9
1001
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add some code to your existing function that first converts **Binary to Int** and then **Int to HexaDecimal** (your code) OR develop some logic to convert Binary to HexaDecimal directly.

Answer (score 2):

This function I wrote is from my library. This library is called the libZ library. This function can convert million of digits of hexadecimal into binary and only limited to how long Python let the strings to be.

If you want to understand how the function worked, I wrote a very detail article on the subject of converting hexadecimal to binary. You can find the article at http://kevinhng86.iblog.website/2017/01/27/working-with-number-converting-binary-and-hexadecimal-python/ .

```
def binhexZ(invalue):
    wmap = {"0000": "0",
            "0001": "1",
            "0010": "2",
            "0011": "3",
            "0100": "4",
            "0101": "5",
            "0110": "6",
            "0111": "7",
            "1000": "8",
            "1001": "9",
            "1010": "A",
            "1011": "B",
            "1100": "C",
            "1101": "D",
            "1110": "E",
            "1111": "F"
            }
    i = 0
    output = ""

    while (len(invalue) % 4 != 0):
        invalue = "0" + invalue

    while (i < len(invalue)):
        output = output + wmap[invalue[i:i + 4]]
        i = i + 4

    output = output.lstrip("0")
    output = "0" if len(output) == 0 else output

    return output
```